# Search data between two tables from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the data only from "*products*" table, the problem is if the data was found from "*categories*" table it will returns empty.

```
SELECT p.code AS CODE, p.model AS NAME 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN categories c 
ON p.category = c.id 
WHERE p.model LIKE "%LAPTOP%" OR c.category_name LIKE "%LAPTOP%"
```

I thought this query will return exact table column you want to achieve if both were connected from this **ON p.category = c.id**.

Comment: give some examples of data, or you can try to create one fiddle from https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: If you only `want to get the data only from "products" table`, then delete `LEFT JOIN.....` and `OR c.category_name LIKE "%LAPTOP%"`. Easy!

Comment: "I thought this query will return exact table column you want to achieve if both were connected from this ON p.category = c.id" If you want exact row for row match, don't you need INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Yes I only want to get the data from products table but I need the categories table so that I can be able to find the list of categories, that's why I'm using LIKE condition:

Example I want to search LAPTOPS from categories, so supposedly it will return all the list of categories which is the products data so once it will return all the list, I want to get only the model and code column from products table.

Comment: INNER JOIN AND LEFT JOIN returns the same value, I already tried it.

Comment: Then please post sample data and expected output you want

Comment: okay wait I will make a table

Comment: Here is the table: 

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7bzbKAJWWeCXWHbYPKkH7Z/5)

Comment: so what I did from my query  is I connect both of them  using 'LEFT JOIN' then with the condition of searching data from model or category_name, if ever the data was found from category_name I expect it will return the modal and code column from products table since they were connected from my query using 'p.category = c.id '

Comment: Oh anyway it was working! hahaha but I don't know why my in my code doesn't work, is it may be the version of mysql? or anyting?
[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7bzbKAJWWeCXWHbYPKkH7Z/8)

Comment: _"INNER JOIN AND LEFT JOIN returns the same value, I already tried it. "_ .. the way your query is right now, of course you'll get the same result. No point in doing a `LEFT JOIN` when you're going to have the second table's (onward) column(s) in `WHERE`. You should know the difference between the `JOIN` variations and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that all your cases is as your sample data in db-fiddle, you could use this query:

```
SELECT p.code AS CODE, p.model, COALESCE(c.category_name, p.model) AS NAME 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN categories c 
ON p.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE p.model LIKE "%LAPTOP%" OR c.category_name LIKE "%LAPTOP%"
```

tested in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7bzbKAJWWeCXWHbYPKkH7Z/7)

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your help, anyway I finally solved it https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7bzbKAJWWeCXWHbYPKkH7Z/8 , but I don't have any idea why in my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me what you really want is something like this:

```
SELECT *
 FROM categories c 
 LEFT JOIN products p 
 ON c.category_id = p.category_id
AND c.category_name LIKE "%LAPTOP%";
```

However, I can't help to think that since you have `p.model LIKE "%LAPTOP%"` in your condition, you're probably aiming for something a little bit different. Check out the result in this fiddle and tell me if this is close to what you're looking for or not:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4016c1e1a09c1d718f06a6605fd9677b

Answer (score 1):

@RobroyBustilloCanales

your query is correct. you have mentioned category_id in product table as text so you need to cast that to integer before join and use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
            SELECT p.code AS CODE, p.model AS NAME 
            FROM products p 
            LEFT JOIN categories c 
            ON cast (p.category_id as INTEGER) = c.category_id
            WHERE p.model LIKE '%LAPTOP%' OR c.category_name LIKE '%LAPTOP%';
```